# PHP - правильно зациклить функцию для парсинга нескольких страниц

Tags: php, циклы, парсер, функции

Добрый день.

Имеется функция для парсинга сайта. Используется библиотека `html_simple_dom_parser`. У меня получается парсить нужную мне информацию об одном объекте, но я не понимаю, как зациклить функцию так, чтобы я мог передавать, например, массив ссылок, и мне выдавалась таблица с множеством объектов.

Код функции:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); 
mb_http_output('UTF-8'); 
mb_http_input('UTF-8'); 
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); 

ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');


    # подключаем библиотеку
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');
    # глобальный массив, который будет заполняться информацией статьи
    $articles = array();
    $URL = '____________________';



    function getArticles($page) {
        global $urls, $articles, $descriptions;

            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load_file($page);

            $items = $html->find('div[class=column]');

                foreach($items as $post) {
                    # выбираем и записываем в массив данные для парсинга
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(0)->children(1)->children(2)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(1)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(2)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(3)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(4)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(5)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(6)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(7)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(8)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(1)->children(9)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(2)->outertext);
                    $articles[] = array(price => $post->children(3)->children(0)->find('a', 1)->outertext);

                    }
}

?>
```

Вызываем функцию и рисуем таблицу:

```
<?php 

getArticles($URL);

            $table = "<table border=1 class='table'><tbody><tr>";
                    #See here the start of the first row
                    foreach($articles as $a => $item) {

                    $table .= "<td>$item[price]</td>";
                    #double quotes for the variables
                    if(($a+1) % 12 == 0)
                    $table .= "</tr><tr>";

                }
                $table .= "</tr></tbody></table>"; 
                #end the row
                #append the text and don't overwrite it at the end
            echo $table;    
?>
```

Результат парсинга

[image: Результат парсинга]

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функцию переписать так

```php
function getArticles($page) {
  $articles = array();
  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load_file($page);

  $items = $html->find('div[class=column]');

  foreach($items as $post) {
    $articles[] = array('price' => $post->children(0)->children(1)->children(2)->outertext);
    .............
    $articles[] = array('price' => $post->children(3)->children(0)->find('a', 1)->outertext);
  }
  return $articles;
}
```

Использовать так

```php
$urls = array(.........);

$table = "<table border=1 class='table'><tbody><tr>";
foreach($urls as $url) {
  $articles = getArticles($url);
  foreach($articles as $a => $item) {
    $table. = "<td>$item[price]</td>";
    if (($a + 1) % 12 == 0)
      $table. = "</tr><tr>";
  }
  $table. = "</tr></tbody></table>";
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь. Немного поправил вывод таблицы и закрыл одинарными кавычками 'price' дабы не ругался. Спасибо @anton-shchyrov!

Comment: @optical-genius Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, то отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 0):

Неоднократно сталкиваюсь с одной и той же проблемой. При парсинге страниц в цикле возникает ошибка 
"Call to a member function find() on null in D:\OpenServer\domains\widgets\parser\prod\server\simple_html_dom.php on line 1129"

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$html->save();

$response = array();

$subPageArr = array();

foreach ($html->find('tr') as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 0) {
        $subPageArr[] =  $value->find('.auction-list-address a', 0)->href;
    }
}

unset($html);

function getArticles($page) {
  $articles = array();
  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load_file($page);

  $item = $html->find('.object-data');

  return $item;
}


foreach($subPageArr as $url) {
    $articles = getArticles($url);

    echo $articles;
}
```

что я делаю не так? Суть задачи такова - На сайте есть куча ссылок на другие страницы, с которых нужно парсить данные, массив ссылок получаю без проблем а вот парсинг этих страниц в цикле ломается.